# javascript embedded video how to know when user watched it

Tags: javascript, wmv, embedded-video

I have an online course. I want to show the user a video with the following:

- it auto starts
- the user cannot move back or forward (showcontrols=false)
- the user cannot go to the the next course page until watching the whole video

Right now I'm missing the last point. I know the video length, so I'm thinking in setting a timer checking for the video position in seconds and compare that to the length. When the current video position is very close to the length, then enable the next button.

How can I accomplish this in a way that is compatible with most browsers? Also, is there a way to know the video length with javascript? (I don't mind entering the length manually)

I have something like this:

```
<embed src="video.wmv" showcontrols="false" width="474" height="356" name="video" autostart="true" loop="false">
```

Comment: What if the user WANTS to go to the next video? Perhaps they've watched this one before and were just reviewing something, or perhaps they "get it" and want to move on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Timeout to enable the next-button:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { 
  //enable the button
}, 400000); //ms until next button is enabled - this is 400 seconds for example
```